# Is struts2-jquery-tree.plugin.jar compatible with struts1.3

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Is struts2-jquery-tree.plugin.jar compatible with struts1.3? Will the plugin be enabled by default?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not compatible. You need Struts2 2.1.x or higher to use the Struts2 jQuery Plugin.